How to install Project Panama?
I've been working on some program with JDK 17 and Maven and some part of it should to be written with Panama.
i've tried to put jextract in my Maven pom.xml dependencies and copypasted the code sample i needed, but got Excpetions.
How to install it and how to make it work when i'll pack my program into a jar file?
The code i want to implement in my program:
import java.lang.invoke.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import jdk.incubator.foreign.*;

/**
 %JDK16%\bin\java -Dforeign.restricted=permit --add-modules jdk.incubator.foreign SetWallpaper.java A.JPG
 */
public class SetWallpaper {
    static final int SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER  = 0x0014;
    static final int SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE    = 0x01;
    static final int SPIF_SENDCHANGE       = 0x02;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        LibraryLookup user32 = LibraryLookup.ofLibrary("user32");
        MethodHandle spi = CLinker.getInstance().downcallHandle(user32.lookup("SystemParametersInfoA").get()
            // BOOL SystemParametersInfoA         (UINT uiAction,  UINT uiParam,   PVOID pvParam,       UINT fWinIni);
            , MethodType.methodType(int.class,     int.class,      int.class,      MemoryAddress.class, int.class)
            , FunctionDescriptor.of(CLinker.C_LONG,CLinker.C_LONG, CLinker.C_LONG, CLinker.C_POINTER,   CLinker.C_LONG));
    
        Path path = Path.of(args[0]).toRealPath();
    
        try (NativeScope scope = NativeScope.unboundedScope()) {
            MemorySegment img = CLinker.toCString(path.toString(), scope);
            int status = (int)spi.invokeExact(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, img.address(), SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
            System.out.println("Changed wallpaper to "+path+" rc="+status+(status == 0 ? " *** ERROR ***": " OK"));
        }
    }
}

Small changes needed for JDK17:
/**
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java --enable-native-access=ALL-UNNAMED --add-modules jdk.incubator.foreign SetWallpaper.java A.JPG
*/
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    System.loadLibrary("user32");
    // BOOL SystemParametersInfoA(UINT uiAction, UINT uiParam, PVOID pvParam, UINT fWinIni);
    MemoryAddress symbol = SymbolLookup.loaderLookup().lookup("SystemParametersInfoW").get();
    MethodHandle SystemParametersInfoW = CLinker.getInstance().downcallHandle(symbol
        , MethodType.methodType(int.class,     int.class,      int.class,      MemoryAddress.class, int.class)
        , FunctionDescriptor.of(CLinker.C_LONG,CLinker.C_LONG, CLinker.C_LONG, CLinker.C_POINTER,   CLinker.C_LONG));

    Path path = Path.of(args[0]).toRealPath();

    try(ResourceScope scope = ResourceScope.newConfinedScope()) {
        SegmentAllocator allocator = SegmentAllocator.arenaAllocator(scope);
        // toCString as WIDE string
        Addressable wide = allocator.allocateArray(CLinker.C_CHAR, (path+"\0").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE));
        int status = (int)SystemParametersInfoW.invokeExact(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, wide.address(), SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
        System.out.println("Changed wallpaper to "+path+" rc="+status+(status == 0 ? " *** ERROR ***": " OK"));
    }
}

this code is from thread: Can I change my Windows desktop wallpaper programmatically in Java/Groovy?
But i can't install Panama
I want my jar file to be a single jar file without a whole jdk folder needed near it
i've tried to put jextract in my Maven pom.xml dependencies and copypasted the code sample i needed, but got Excpetions.

I want my jar file to be a single jar file without a whole jdk folder needed near it, a jar file needs a Java runtime to run, one way or another. If the jar is not bundled with a runtime image, the end user that is running the jar would have to source a Java 17 runtime image that can run the jar from somewhere themselves. path/to/java17/runtime/image/bin/java -Dforeign.restricted=permit --add-modules jdk.incubator.foreign -jar app.jar. I recommend creating a runtime image for Java 17 with jlink, and bundling that with the jar + a launcher script, instead. Much easier for end-users.

I’m confused. By “Panama” do you mean JEP 454: Foreign Function & Memory API? That feature was delivered in Java 22. Why are you asking about Java 17 and preview feature?

Basil is right. Your current code won't work with Java 22 or up, because the FFM API has had some big overhauls. For instance, ResourceScope no longer exists.

"got Excpetions" that's not really helpful to understand the issue. Share the exceptions.

The code that you copied from my answer referenced does not use jextract, so your question does not contain any detail of what you are doing. You will save yourself a lot of grief if you switch to JDK22 (foreign memory API is delivered) and download compatible jextract for JDK22, then edit the question with problems generating SystemParametersInfoW api call.

I would not place jextract in your POM. I would run it once, offline, and place the output in your project.
